# Shell script: Using own IP adresss as variable

Tags: linux, bash, shell

I have to write a shell script which initializes docker swarm.

I need to pass the own IP address as argument:

```
 sudo docker swarm init --advertise-addr 167.172.176.134
```

How can I do this dynamically?
I know the `ifconfig` command, which allows me to see the IP, but I can not pass the whole thing as variable. It should look like this

```
ip = ifconfig["IP"]
sudo docker swarm init --advertise-addr $ip
```

Comment: `hostname -i` or `hostname -I` might help. Whether this works depends on your Linux distribution.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The following command will return your public ip address

```
curl ifconfig.me
```

Please try the following

```
ip=$(curl ifconfig.me)
sudo docker swarm init --advertise-addr $ip
```

Comment: Is this safe? Seems like they could inject something, no?

Comment: @Evert, they could give you wrong *information,* yes. But they're not *running* anything on your box to do this. It's no different to bringing up https://ifconfig.me/ in your browser. In any case, you could check what it gives you before using it if you're concerned - a regex check for valid IP is fairly simple.

Comment: @evert: What do you mean with inject? The script lives on my github account and will be used to set up some services in a Swarm cluster.

Comment: ifconfig.me should be a relatively reliable

Comment: `ifconfig.me` is controlled by someone else, it's not something on your computer. They can return something that takes over your machine. So don't do this for anything sensitive. Worth noting it also doens't use SSL, so easier to MITM.

Comment: Lastly, if that service is down for any reason, your script won't run. So if it's anything critical, this seems like a silly dependency.

Comment: @Evert, so you could just set up your *own* on-prem server to do the same thing if you're concerned with the external one being down. That gives you more control but, of course, your *own* server may also go down :-) I'm not *entirely* convinced it could take over your machine with something you treat as a simple text variable. I wouldn't do `$(${ip})` for example but any use where you treat it as a string to be compared should be fine.

Comment: You can specify https:// for ssl. I belive ifconfig.me is the considered to be standard api for this.

Comment: Anyway, I have some doubt that OP wants their public ip for this. I'd assume that this needs to be bound to a local interface? The example uses a 169 address. Who runs this kinda thing on a public ip? Maybe I don't understand docker swam well enough =)

Comment: @Evert https://whatismyipaddress.com/ip/167.172.176.134 It is a public ip.